# Attribute Error during countplot in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I have Pandas DataFrame like this: `data = pd.DataFrame({"Risk":["good", "good", "bad", "good", "bad", "bad", "good"]})`
And I want to make seaborn countplot which will count amount of "good" and "bad", so I have a code:

```
ax = sns.countplot(x="Risk", data=data)
ax
```

But when I want to use above code I have error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

I want to achieve plot like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check last element in your data. Or, you may have given data=data.Risk as an arguement to countplot(). Otherwise, code is working fine. You need to invoke show()  method using an object of matplotlib.

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import seaborn as sns
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({"Risk":["good", "good", "bad", "good", "bad", "bad", "good"]})
>>> ax = sns.countplot(x="Risk", data=data)
>>> plt.show()
```

You had that error because in Data sns.countplot() tries to search data of Risk in Dataset data. It tries following function.

> > > data.get('Risk')
> > >       When you execute above written code, Risk series data will be printed. In your code, data had a list as an input so it generated an error that get is not supported by list. It is used with Pandas DataFrame.
> > >       [This image contains count according to the Risk Categories i.e Good and Bad.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKhTL.png)

Answer (score -1):

May be check your data again?

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({"Risk":["good", "good", "bad", "good", "bad", "bad", "good"]})
ax = sns.countplot(x="Risk", data=data)
ax
```

Running this shows the plot perfectly:

[image]

Comment: It really does not work, why I have mentioned attritube error ? What is wrong ? Risk is as str column

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. In my end, it's working just fine. Maybe the error is showing up from somewhere else in your code. 

Did you check the dataframe? Is it properly formatted? Run the code snippet in a new python file. Also count plot works fine on `str` type column.